# Where can I find an intensive course in documentary photography?

Tags: course

I am looking for documentary photography courses in English. What I am looking is intensive 3-7 days of hard work and learning on the subject.

Course location: preferably UK, but I can also consider any European based school.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[London School of Photography](http://www.londonschoolofphotography.co.uk) is offering 5-day courses on "Photojournalism & Street Photography". The courses run from Monday to Friday, with Wednesday reserved for homework on your own.

The courses are held roughly monthly with next one starting on July 11th. Price: £595.

Answer (score 2):

There are loosely three general options for courses: self paced training from training materials, such as those offered by [the Open University](http://www3.open.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/course/t189.htm) in the UK; brand specific courses, such as those endorsed by Canon and offered by [Experience Seminars](http://www.experience-seminars.co.uk/) in the UK; and also courses that are for specific disciplines within photography. Of course, all of these *type* of course will be available around the world, with differing suppliers.

The latter type of course sounds like the closest to what you're after (based on what you've put in your original question), and the best information on this sort of course is generally the classifieds section of the local photography press.

Comment: Intensive workshop is this what I really need. I can go over technical details etc... but I will not learn me much about soul looking for soul and story in photos - workshops are usually very inspiring in that matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't taken this workshop personally, but I've seen her lectures which are profound. If you like Mary Ellen Mark's vision, then learn from the master herself:

http://www.maryellenmark.com/workshops/oaxaca/oaxaca_workshop_info.html

Comment: Pretty far from me, but looks promising. Thanks!